# React native: how do I make Modal and KeyboardAvoidingView animation faster?

Tags: react-native

I have a React-native's `KeyboardAvoidingView` wrap an input:

```
<Modal
  visible={this.props.showModal}
  animationType='slide'
  presentationStyle='pageSheet'
>
  <KeyboardAvoidingView
    behavior={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'padding' : 'height'}
    keyboardVerticalOffset={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 56 : 32}
  >
    <SearchResultsList />
    <Divider />
    <View style={styles.headerWrapper}>
      <TextInput
        blurOnSubmit={false}
        autoFocus
        style={styles.textInput}
        value={this.state.searchPhrase}
        onChangeText={text => this.onChangeText(text)}
      />
      <IconButton icon='close' onPress={() => this.onChangeText('')} />
    </View>
  </KeyboardAvoidingView>
</Modal>
```

The problem with this code is that animation takes forever. First, modal show up, then keyboard and then (!!!) the input animates up. Is there way to make both keyboard and input show up simultaneously with the modal? Or, at least, is there way to make input move up along with keyboard, not after keyboard?

Comment: Is it resolved I am facing the same issue, Please help.

Comment: the only way I found is a thorough manual adjustment using react-native-reanimated